# How to get all the days/dates in current week, this month, this year using the current date (today) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application i have to show list of working hours by date in a table view,

Here i have 5 scenarios

1. Today's projects, working hours
2. Selected date projects, hours
3. Cureent week (sunday-saturday)
4. Current month (working hours in january, February if it is feb march if it is march)
5. Current year (all working hours in 2013)

i have implemented sqlite queries as follows,

**1. Select Date, ProjectTitle, WorkingHours, sum(WorkingHours) from ProjDetailsTable where date = toDaysDate**

**2.  Select Date, ProjectTitle, WorkingHours, sum(WorkingHours) from ProjDetailsTable where date = selecteDate**

*`I have done for the fist two scenarions`*

***For the 3,4,5 scenarios***

---

```
3. Select Date, ProjectTitle, WorkingHours, sum(WorkingHours) from ProjDetailsTable where 
Date between two Dates
```

---

But My problem is if I have the dates

```
Is there any logic to get the starting for
current week, current month, current year
```

Note : not the 7 days back, not the 30 months back and not the 365 days back.

My requirement is:

**`if Current date is Feb-13-2020 WednesDay`**

**This week:** *Feb-9 to Today*

**This Month:** *Feb-1 to Today*

**This Year:** *Jan-1-2020 to Today*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will give you basic idea how you have to proceed: 
For other scenarios you can work out

```
- (NSDate *)firstDayOfWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
      NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
      NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

     [comps setWeekday:2]; // 2: monday
     return [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
  }
```

Comment: Thank yu so much its works fine Is there any way to get the fisartday of the month and first day of the year

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for getting current year & month.
Simply add these to previous answer as my friend had suggested.

```
NSInteger year = [comps year];
NSInteger month = [comps month];
```

Now, I think if you're getting current year & month, you can set manually for 1st date. and perform as you want.

Main thing is to get weekday ..
Thanks.