# How to get first date of MONTH, and first date of YEAR for a incoming date. in iPhone Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all the days/dates in current week, this month, this year using the current date (today) in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272489/how-to-get-all-the-days-dates-in-current-week-this-month-this-year-using-the-c)

I need to get the first day of Month,  first day of Year for a date

(Most of times input date is current date `[NSDate date]`)

could you please suggest how to get it,

E.G. **todays current date** = ***`3-MAY-2015`***

Output needed as follows:

**First_Date_month** = ***`1-MAY-2015`***

**First_Date_year** = ***`1-JAN-2015`***

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: There's plenty of material avaliable only on this forum, make a few searches. You could also start by telling us how you format your dates and what isn't working.

Comment: This seems to be essentially a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272489/how-to-get-all-the-days-dates-in-current-week-this-month-this-year-using-the-c. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the day month and year using NSDateComponents and can make NSDate as you want

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setDay:1];
self.currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
int m = components.month;
int y = components.year;
int d = components.day;


NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd"];
NSDate *firstDateOfMonth = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ 01",y,m]];
NSDate *firstDateOfYear = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 01 01",y]];
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine but it has back time GMT +5.30 (My loc is India) any solutin for that

Comment: google it .. NSDateFormatter will help you